# Include shared library into Linux application using CMake – GCC linker errors

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake

I have no trouble building my application under Visual Studio's environment, but due to lack of experience, I am having trouble under Linux/GCC.  Although **GCC compiles my app successfully**, but it reports **linker errors**.

The first thing I did was to build a shared library using CMakeLists.txt.  The file has no ‘make install’ so I manually copied the shared library file to a global location as follows:

```
sudo cp libibpp.a /usr/local/lib/
```

Since applications built with the IBPP library require you to include a single header file, I copied it to a global location:

```
sudo cp ibpp.h /usr/local/include/
```

So far, so good but when I run CMake for my application, I am getting linker errors such as:

```
undefined reference to ‘isc_create_database’
```

I am successfully using many ‘shared libraries’ in my application (such as Boost Regex/Filesystem/Chrono/DateTime/Thread).  The only ‘static library’ that I am using is IBPP (libibpp.a).
I suspect that I am missing something in my application’s CMakeListst.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(myapp)
file(GLOB src "*.h" "*.cpp")
add_executable(myapp ${src})
target_link_libraries(myapp ibpp icuuc icudata boost_regex boost_system boost_filesystem 
boost_chrono boost_date_time boost_thread pthread)
add_definitions(-DIBPP_LINUX)
```

Can someone provide me with some hints as to why I get linker errors related to IBPP?

UPDATED:

User n.m. asked me to build using the VERBOSE option, so here is the output:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/appServer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/app_env.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/app_setting.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/authenticationServer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/bustacheTestStencil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/commonKeys.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/dataFetcher.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/fighterKeys.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/fighterProfileJsonGenerator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/fighterProfileMarkupGenerator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/fighterStorage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/forwardProxyServer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/headerProcessor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/homepageStencil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/httpUtils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/locale.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/markupServer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/myTools.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/stdafx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/unicodeFunctions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/utils.cpp.o  -o myapp -libpp -licutu -licutest -licuio -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lbustache -lboost_thread -lpthread 
//usr/local/lib/libibpp.a(_ibpp.cpp.o): In function `ibpp_internals::GDS::Call()':
_ibpp.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `isc_create_database'
_ibpp.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `isc_attach_database'
....
_ibpp.cpp:(.text+0x2bd): undefined reference to `isc_service_start'
_ibpp.cpp:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `isc_service_query'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/build.make:640: recipe for target 'myapp' failed
make[2]: *** [myapp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/carol/Documents/vm_shared/AppServer/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/carol/Documents/vm_shared/AppServer/build'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: If you can, please increase your minimum CMake version to something in the 3's.  How are you linking against boost, or even including its headers?  I don't see a `find_package(Boost)` command in your CMakeLists.txt.  You should use `find_library` to find the ibpp library.

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and show the *linker invocation*.

Comment: @John, hi, I just checked and the version is cmake version 3.10.2.  Above is my entire CMakeLists.txt. which works fine if I remove the 'ibpp' library.  Should I post the CMakeLists.txt that I used to build the IBPP library?

Comment: @n.m., hello, I added VERBOSE output to my original question. Even though I got no errors building libibpp.a, is it possible that something is wrong with the CMake text file I used to build IBPP? Please advise. Oh, and please note that my linker problem began when I introduced libibpp.a.

Comment: On my system isc_create_database is in two libraries, called fbclient and gds. (Actually both are symbolic links to the same library). Neither is used in your linker invocation. You probably need to add one of those to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: I cannot believe this `CMakeLists.txt` works with VisualStudio. You are missing `find_package` calls.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak, I'm using the Visual Studio environment for building on Windows and CMake in an attempt to build with Linux/GCC.  Sorry about not being clear about that.  I'll modify my original post.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran then you need to put a little more effort into your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @n.m., thank you for your fbclient suggestion, that did was it!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to comment by n.m. above.  Since I was not including libfbclient, I was getting the "undefined references to 'isc_create_database', and other 'isc_...' messages.

Using the settings below, I am now able to use my precompiled/built IBPP library instead of having to include the source code into my application!

Here is a simplified, very barebones CMakeLists.txt that demonstrates what is required to get your IBPP.a implemented into your app without having to include the IBPP source into your app:

```
file(GLOB src "*.cpp")
add_executable(myapp ${src})
target_link_libraries(myapp ibpp fbclient)
```

Make note of the order, libibpp must be before libfbclient.